# Example of Google page ranking algorithm?

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, discrete-mathematics

I read about the Google page ranking algorithm from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank

[image: Google Page Ranking simple algorithms].

My question is why only outbound links are used in page rank calculation? Do inbound links not affect the page rank by any means ?

Comment: A link from page $A$ to page $B$ is outbound from $A$ and inbound to $B.$  So if you consider all outbound links in the network, you are automatically including all inbound links as well.

Comment: Thanks @WillOrrick. Wow! How simple and great answer it is :)

Comment: There are similar algorithms which also consider outlinks, such as Jon Kleinberg's [HITS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HITS_algorithm).